# How does GitHub detect signing in/out?

Tags: javascript, github

When opening several tabs/windows on the GitHub website, if you happen to sign in/out on one of these, you get a notification on all others invinting you to reload to refresh your session state.

How is that done?

All I know so far is the pages HTML code contains some hidden SVG graphic + spans which are activated through JavaScript :

```
<div class="js-stale-session-flash stale-session-flash flash flash-warn flash-banner d-none">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-alert" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16"><path d="M8.865 1.52c-.18-.31-.51-.5-.87-.5s-.69.19-.87.5L.275 13.5c-.18.31-.18.69 0 1 .19.31.52.5.87.5h13.7c.36 0 .69-.19.86-.5.17-.31.18-.69.01-1L8.865 1.52zM8.995 13h-2v-2h2v2zm0-3h-2V6h2v4z"></path></svg>
  <span class="signed-in-tab-flash">You signed in with another tab or window. <a href="">Reload</a> to refresh your session.</span>
  <span class="signed-out-tab-flash">You signed out in another tab or window. <a href="">Reload</a> to refresh your session.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe they repeatedly check a cookie. Or the logout-tab messages the others that a logout has happened. Or something else.

Comment: With websocket on https://live.github.com/_sockets/...

Answer (score 12):

This is done with storageEvents.

Basically, the `Storage` interface emits [`storage` event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html) on global objects which it affects.

Essentially, on each generated GitHub page load, GitHub sets the meta tag with the name '`user-login`'. The value will be the currently logged in user.

For example, if I view the source code for a page that I have loaded in GitHub, the source code contains this line:

```
<meta name="user-login" content="timgws">
```

Then, each time the page loads, the content's value is retrieved, and stored inside LocalStorage. Roughly, with jQuery the code is:

```
localStorage.setItem("logged-in", $("meta[name='user-login']").attr("content"));
```

Finally, the last magic trick is to listen for the `storage` event, pick up if the username has changed and then switch the visibility of the `flash` class.

```
var currentUser = localStorage.getItem("logged-in");
window.addEventListener("storage", function (event) {
    if (event.storageArea === localStorage && event.key === "logged-in"
        && event.newValue !== currentUser) {

        $('.flash').removeClass('d-none');
    }
});
```

You might want to add some code to differentiate between users logging in and out (which should be pretty easy by comparing the value of `currentUser`)